# Python, acces a dict in another module (file)

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a main file for my main code, one for my classes and one for a price list containing dicts.

i want to acces the dict file to get the relevant prices.
The way it looks now (doesn't work & ignore the indents) is:

---

```
import price_list
```

## main class

```
class Product:

def __init__(self):

    self.price_code = "selected_price_code"
    self.codes = ["code1", "code2"]
```

## then a function to get the prices

```
def price(self):
    prices = []
    for i in self.codes:
        prices.append(price_list.self.price_code[I])
    return sum(prices)
```

As you can see it goes wrong with accessing the self.price_code.
What would be a better way to do this? I feel like im overcomplicating things.

The error message now is: [ AttributeError: module 'price_list' has no attribute 'self' ] I know this is because I am doing it wrong but what would be a better way to use a self.input to acces the dict in another file?

Comment: Please correct code indentation and include any error messages.

Comment: I corrected the indentation. The error message now is: [ AttributeError: module 'price_list' has no attribute 'self' ] I know this is because I am doing it wrong but what would be a better way to use a self.input to acces the dict in another file?

Comment: Are you trying to use class as database for your prices/codes? It looks weird... but you could simply go for class variables if you wanted to store consts (so don't declare your variables in init but directly under class and then access them like ClassName.foo)

Comment: not right now, when everything works I want to store everything in a database. For now I need a simpel mockup that works.

Comment: Simplest thing would be to either store your dicts directly in a file or if you really want to use class then store your consts as class vars :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to instantiate your class if you want to access its properties which you initiate in `__init__`.

I'm not sure if I understand well enough your idea but you could simply store your consts directly in a file like this:

Your foo.py:

```
price_code = "selected_price_code"
codes = ["code1", "code2"]
```

And then access them in your other module like this:

```
from foo import price_code, codes

# use price_code and codes
```

If you prefer to use a class as container then maybe go for class vars:

foo.py:

```
Product:
    price_code = "selected_price_code"
    codes = ["code1", "code2"]
```

And then access your consts like this:

```
from foo import Product

# Use Product.price_code and Product.codes
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's put some order here.
As per what I got the file system is:

```
project_folder
--main.py -> here there is Product class
--price_list.py -> here is written the class price_list dict
```

**price_list.py**

```
price_list = { "code1": 5, "code2": 10 }
```

**app.py**

```
# import price_list dict from price_list module
from price_list import price_list

# this class gets the price code as parameter
class Product(price_code):
    def __init__(self, price_code):
        # initialize price code
        self.price_code = price_code

    # return the price of the selected code
    def get_price(self):
        return price_list[self.price_code]

# create a Product instance
product_one = Product("code1")

# get product instance price
product_one_price = product_one.get_price()   # returns 5
```

I suggest to you to:

- make a pseudocode to get clear what you want to do
- study how imports works: [article](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)
- study how classes works: [article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:%7E:text=Python%20classes%20provide%20all%20the,class%20with%20the%20same%20name.)